# Why is this tiny programe causing infinite loop?

Tags: c, windows-xp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*MYPROC)(LPTSTR);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE LibHandle;
    MYPROC ProcAdd;
    LibHandle = LoadLibrary("msvcrt.dll");
    printf ("%#p\n", LibHandle);
    ProcAdd = (MYPROC)GetProcAddress(LibHandle, "system");
    printf ("%#p\n", ProcAdd);
    (ProcAdd)("cmd.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is supposed to invoke a `cmd.exe` command then exit,but it turns out will cause infinite loop,why?

It's outputing this for me:

```
0X77BE0000
0X77BF93C7
0X77BE0000
0X77BF93C7
0X77BE0000
0X77BF93C7
0X77BE0000
0X77BF93C7
0X77BE0000
0X77BF93C7
0X77BE0000
0X77BF93C7
0X77BE0000
0X77BF93C7
0X77BE0000
...
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an infinte loop and not just a hang? Also, this is a very odd way to call 'system'!

Comment: It works for me. Can you describe your problem in details?

Comment: @Anton Semenov , @Skizz ,I've pasted the output above.

Comment: Wow, try to debug it step by step. I have no ideas why it behaves this way

Comment: Did you name your own program "cmd" by any chance?

Comment: @Ben Schwehn,yes,my programe is named cmd.

Comment: Well, there's your answer then, you call your own program recursively because it comes before the widows cmd in the search path (because it's in the current directory)

Comment: @Skizz, I wonder if there's any other way to call a function in a dll at run time?

Comment: @compile-fan: You don't need to import the msvcrt.dll, that's already done for you, so you can just do `system ('cmd.exe');` instead of all the code you've got. It is also possible to statically link to DLLs so that they get loaded at the same time as the executable and you can call functions without having to call `GetProcAddress` (this is how all C run time and Win32 calls are done). If you haven't got an import library for a DLL or want to have a plug-in style system then you need to use the `GetProcAddress` method for each DLL.

Comment: @Skizz,but my way of calling a process is more extensible/general,which works under all circumstances,right?

Comment: @compile-fan: I can't think of any situation where calling `system` directly in code won't work. Your example is just duplicating what the OS is doing anyway. Plus, it will fail if the DLL is missing (but it will also fail the same way if you just put in the `system` call and don't statically link to the run time library). It is also Win32 specific, the code you wrote won't work on any other OS whereas the straight `system` call will (for most OSs). Why write 7 lines of code when one line does the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, and trying this out confirms this, is that you are calling your executable 'cmd.exe', which means the system call is invoking a new version of your program.

Comment: you mentioned that *this is a very odd way to call 'system'!'* ,I wonder if there's any other way to call a function in a dll at run time?